# Difference between creating new environment with and without cloning base in conda

Tags: anaconda, conda

In official conda documentation a new environment is created by:

`conda create --name myenv`

But I found it unreliable, so I usually create a new environment with cloning base:

`conda create --name myenv --clone base`

As I understand, if you are cloning any other environment, you are making an exact copy of all the packages in that environment. But in case of creating a new environment without cloning, you still get all the base packages by default. But if you've created a new environment without cloning the base, there might occur problems with installing some new packages because they might need to update some dependencies from the base.

So, I wonder what is really the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The first case,

```
conda create --name myenv
```

without specifying any packages creates a totally empty environment with no packages. Thus, if you run (say) Python, your shell will still run the Python from the base environment and you'll see all your packaages. If you install Python into your new environment (either when you create it or after):

```
conda install -n myenv python
```

And then run Python, you'll see that there are no packages available. You can see further confirmation of that by writing

```
conda list -n myenv
```

which should tell you that there are no packages in `myenv`.

Comment: Thanks! What do you think about the dependencies problem? Sometimes, when I tried to install a new package into non-cloned environment it required updating dependency from base, but it doesn't have permission. Is the best solution to create new environment by cloning base or smth else?

Comment: What do you mean, required updating from base? Can you please post the entire output of the operation by editing your original question?